# invoke spring boot service by rpc way not http

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, rpc

I am trying to deploy my service on a cluster. The service is written by spring boot.

As we know, we can invoke a spring boot function, like this:

```
/user/{id}
```

will be show `User` details.

In fact the whole function request is a `HTTP` request, it is this:

```
http://host/user/{id}
```

And I deploy the function on a cluster, for a higher performance, I need to the service is invoked by `RPC` way, not `HTTP`, may be:

```
rpc://user/{id}
```

What should I do?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about this ? https://github.com/making/msgpack-rpc-jersey-blank

Comment: RPC... Higher performance... Why would you get higher performance when using RPC... It depends on what RPC mechanism you use, and it will add to complexity. HTTP is way easier and isn't slow by itself, if something is slow there is something in your app  or infrastructure that is making it slow. Slapping RPC on it won't make things better IMHO...